# access Alexa Session persistence from other service

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have a Alexa hosted skill. I am trying to find a way to access  persistenceAdapter.S3PersistenceAdapter() from some other places ( e.g. angular 2.x). Can this be done, or I have to use other database to replace S3? If that is the case, which database is recommended?

I use some sample code to access S3 from alexa skill. I have no idea how attributesManager work, just copy and paste.

```
.withPersistenceAdapter(
        new persistenceAdapter.S3PersistenceAdapter({bucketName:process.env.S3_PERSISTENCE_BUCKET})
    )
```

and

```
const attributesManager = handlerInput.attributesManager;
const sessionAttributes = await attributesManager.getPersistentAttributes() || {};
const temperature = sessionAttributes.hasOwnProperty('temperature') ? sessionAttributes.temperature : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

S3 isn't a database - S3 is object storage. If a database is what you need, you could use DynamoDB instead. It sounds like it is - you wouldn't normally use S3 for this.

Anyway, you'll not be able to use the ASK SDK in an Angular or other (non Alexa skill) project. But, you could connect to S3 (or DynamoDB) using the AWS SDK.

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js

You have 3x types of attributes for Alexa - request, session and persistent. I noticed your variable is named `sessionAttributes` but you're doing `getPersistentAttributes`.

Here's an example of how you'd use the `withPersistentAdapter` - https://www.talkingtocomputers.com/alexa-skills-kit-ask-sdk-v2#data-persistence

But here's an example if you use DynamoDB. It's simpler IMO:

```
module.exports.handler = Alexa.SkillBuilders.standard()
    .addRequestHandlers(/* your handlers */)
    .withTableName(/* your table name (string) */)
    .withDynamoDbClient()
    .lambda()
}
```

Then you could do something like (in an async function):

```
const att = await attributesManager.getPersistentAttributes()
const temperature = att.temperature ? att.temperature : 0
```

But of course, you need to save the attribute there first, if you want to access it. For example (in an async function):

```
const att = await attributesManager.getPersistentAttributes()

await attributesManager.setPersistentAttributes( { ...att, temperature: 10 }) // set the value
await attributesManager.savePersistentAttributes() // save it
```

Comment: Not what I am looking for but thank you. The problem is i am using alexa host, so I cannot config permission for that s3. I will try to move lambda in my aws account, not sure if that can work

Answer (score 0):

You can use S3 buckets the syntax looks like this, they do have get,set and save like the persistence attributes as in the example above and more on this you can go here the [Amazon Docs at the bottom.](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/manage-attributes.html)

```
const { S3PersistenceAdapter } = require('ask-sdk-s3-persistence-adapter');
const S3PersistenceAdapter = new S3PersistenceAdapter({ bucketName : 'FooBucket' })
```